# concatenate each value of argv with a string

Tags: c, concatenation, argv

I'm working on a C program that get the command line arguments and append to them a file extension.

The execution will be something like this:
`>myprogram file1 file2`
and will execute another program that will use as argument `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`.
I tried doing that would add the extension and run one command (s1 is the path and s2 is `argv[i]` on a loop:

```
int getfile(char *s1, char *s2){
char *str2 = malloc(sizeof(s2)+3);
strcpy(str2,s2);
strcat(str2,".txt");
execl(s1,"program",str2,NULL);
exit(0); 
}
```

The function will run the program for one file (`>program file1.txt` and `>program file2.txt`), but I will need to find a way to run it this way (`>program file1.txt file2.txt`).

I tried to modify argv directly, but I was unsuccessful.

Any advise?

Comment: Use `strlen` for length, not `sizeof`. You also need four extra characters, not three.

Comment: Also, for appending `.txt`, you need 5 extra characters, not 3.

Comment: @H2CO3, Yeah, I guess I was counting the null already in `s2`, but using `strlen` doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char *buffer;
   char command[512];
   int i = 1;
   for(i = 1; i < argc; i++){
     buffer = malloc(strlen(argv[i]) + 5);
     strcpy(buffer,argv[i]);
     strcat(buffer,".txt");
     sprintf(command,"touch %s\0",buffer);
     system(command);
     free(buffer);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

A simple program that has no error checking, and I like to explicitly add the string terminator.

Comment: You don't need that `'\0'`. Really.

Comment: This code does the same thing as the code I wrote on the intial post, it run the program with the individual argument (`>program file1.txt` program file2.txt`), but what I'm looking for is to run it this way '>program file1.txt file2.txt`

Comment: Made some minor changes to the code, so it can run all the arguments in a single command line.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, int *argv[]){
    if(argc==1){
        printf("You have not entered anything!\n"); 
        return 0; 
    }
    char *arr=malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
    int i; 
    strcat(arr, argv[0]);
    strcat(arr, " ");  
    for(i=0;i<argc-1;i++){
        strcat(arr,argv[i+1]); 
        strcat(arr,".txt"); 
        strcat(arr," "); 

        strcat(arr,"\0"); 
    }

    printf("%s\n",arr);
    free(arr); 
    return 0; 

}
```